# Detect jailbroken bypass in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, jailbreak

My Xamarin based iOS application should not run in jailbroken devices. This is due to a IS audit. I have implemented the jailbroken detect mechanism. But I cannot find a way to detect whether someone using a jailbroken bypass method like for example A-bypass, shadow tweaks. Anyone with these tweaks can easily by pass the jailbroken detect code.

This is the class I used,

```cs
    [assembly: Dependency(typeof(CheckHardware))]
    namespace CustApp.iOS
    {
        public class CheckHardware : IHardwareSecurity
        {
    
            public CheckHardware()
            {
            }
    
            public bool IsJailBreaked()
            {
    
                if (isPath() || canCreateFile() || isOpenLink())
                {
                    return true;
    
                }
                else
                {
    
                    return false;
    
                }
    
            }
    
            private bool isPath()
            {
    
                bool res = false;
    
                List<string> pathList = new List<string>
                 {
                     "/Applications/Cydia.app",
                     "/Applications/Checkra1n.app",
                     "/Applications/FakeCarrier.app",
                     "/Applications/Icy.app",
                     "/Applications/IntelliScreen.app",
                     "/Applications/MxTube.app",
                     "/Applications/RockApp.app",
                     "/Applications/SBSettings.app",
                     "/Applications/WinterBoard.app",
                     "/Applications/blackra1n.app",
                     "/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/LiveClock.plist",
                     "/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Veency.plist",
                     "/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib",
                     "/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.ikey.bbot.plist",
                     "/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.saurik.Cydia.Startup.plist",
                     "/etc/apt",
                     "/private/var/lib/apt",
                     "/private/var/lib/apt/",
                     "/private/var/lib/cydia",
                     "/private/var/mobile/Library/SBSettings/Themes",
                     "/private/var/stash",
                     "/private/var/tmp/cydia.log",
                     "/usr/bin/sshd",
                     "/var/cache/apt",
                     "/var/lib/apt",
                     "/usr/libexec/sftp-server",
                     "/usr/sbin/sshd",
                     "/bin/bash",
                     "/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib",
                     "/var/lib/cydia"
                 };
    
                foreach (var fullPath in pathList)
                {
                    if (File.Exists(fullPath))
                    {
                        res = true;
                    }
                }
    
                return res;
    
            }
    
            private bool canCreateFile()
            {
    
                try
                {
                    File.WriteAllText("/private/jailbreak.txt", "This is a test.");
                    return true;
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                    return false;
                }
    
            }
    
            private bool isOpenLink()
            {
    
                if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(NSUrl.FromString("cydia://package/com.example.package")))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
    
            public bool IsInEmulator()
            {
                bool isSimulator = Runtime.Arch == Arch.SIMULATOR;
                return isSimulator;
            }
    
    
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Check this library [BreachDetector](https://github.com/nmilcoff/BreachDetector)

Comment: @FabriBertani not success. still not identified as jailbroke device after using shadow tweak

Comment: That suggests `Shadow` is currently ahead of the detection code. I recommend opening an issue at BreachDetector github. Also, BreachDetector repo text has urls to the libraries it uses on each platform; might be worth opening an issue at the corresponding library for the platform you are testing on. `rootbeer` doc says: `Remember root==god, so there's no 100% guaranteed way to check for root!`.